# What kind of sub-contractor do I use for cutting out a window in a wall that the kitchen and living room share?

Tags: contractors

I'm sorry for this very basic question but I know that plumbers deal with pipes, electricians deal with wiring, etc. but what is the name of the kind of sub-contractor that can cut a make a pass through window in a wall that the kitchen and living share?  A carpenter?

Answer (score 6):

If the wall you are dealing with has electrical and plumbing then you need a general contractor, who may sub out some parts of the job as needed to get the right specialties.

If it's just the wall w/ no wiring or plumbing then generally you need a carpenter and a finish carpenter or someone who does both.